# Prove or disprove: if $f(n)= o(g(n))$ and $h=\omega(1)$ then, $f(h(n))= o(g(h(n)))$

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Prove or disprove:
if $f(n)= o(g(n))$ and $h=\omega(1)$ then, $f(h(n))= o(g(h(n)))$

ive tried to approach it with limits calculation, but no matter which arguments I used the equation seems to be proven.

ex:

Let $f(x) = n$, $g(x) = n^2$, and $h(x)=2^n$.

$\lim_{x\to \infty} = \cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \cfrac{n}{n^2}=0$

$\lim_{x\to \infty} = \cfrac{h(x)}{1}= 2^n=\infty$

$\lim_{x\to \infty} = \cfrac{f(h(x))}{g(h(x))}= \cfrac{2^n}{2^{n^2}}=2^{n-n^2}=2^{n^2(\cfrac{1}{n}-1)}=2^{-\infty} = 0$

how do I prove or disprove this kind of question properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are free to assume that they are general functions, then you can take:

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} x & ;x\in \mathbb{N} \\
1 & ;\text{else} \end{cases} \qquad
g(x)= \begin{cases} x^2 & ;x\in \mathbb{N} \\
1 & ;\text{else} \end{cases} \qquad \text{and} \qquad h(x)=x+\frac{1}{2} $$

Then $h(n)=n+\frac{1}{2}$ and:

$$ \frac{f\big(h(n) \big)}{g\big( h(n) \big)} \equiv 1 $$

The condition only gives you an idea how $f$ and $g$ behave relative to one another where the argument is a natural number. But you seem to have freedom with regards to how they behave elsewhere. That's my idea at least.

I can add though that if $h(n)\in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n$, then the relation must hold since $\frac{f\circ h(n)}{g\circ h(n)}$ is a subseqeunce of $\frac{f(n)}{h(n)}$ which must converge to the same limit.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood the answer.
if the limit is equal to 1 then it's not $o$ rather $O$ and that disprove it. 
yet you have added that it can be proven.
Could you elaborate?

Comment: In the general case, I think what I wrote constitutes a counter example. But in my counter example, $h(n)$ is not a natural number for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I've stated however that if you restrict yourself to cases where $h(n)\in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n$, as you tried in your "counter-example", the result will indeed hold.

Comment: However the answer to your original question, without further conditions on the functions seems to be false, and you can construct many counter examples.

Comment: So basically what you saying is if the function is $h,g,f\in N$ so the statement is true by the definition of the subsequence of $\cfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} $ and if I implement numbers that are $r\in R$ the statement are disprove?

Comment: If I understand your phrasing correctly, then I think the answer is yes though what you what wrote isn't exact. For general functions only satisfying the conditions you wrote originally, the answer is false and can only be disproven.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur could you please elaborate on those functions..? I'm also trying to properly understand what is the functions used to disprove the question.
$ f(x)=x\cdot \chi_{\mathbb{N}}(x)+1\cdot \big( 1-\chi_{\mathbb{N}}(x) \big)$
when using the \chi with natural numbers do you mean that I can choose a positive natural number to place in the function and it will disprove?

Comment: I'll edit my answer so the functions are easier to read.